# Sustituir numero de input

Tags: jquery, formularios, input

necesito cambiar el texto del segundo input que quede numero sin puntos ni el signo, solo el numero, el primer input se escribe el numero y se visualiza bien el segundo input es donde estara el mismo valor agregado pero solo visualizandose el numero, ese input estara oculto

```js
    $("#currency-field").keyup(function () {
        var value = $(this).val();
        $("#face_value").val(value);
    });
    const number = document.querySelector('.number');
    
    function getInputValue(inputElement) {
      return parseInt(inputElement.value.replace(/\D/g, ""));
    }
    
    function formatInputValue(inputElement) {
      let n = getInputValue(inputElement);
      inputElement.value = Number.isNaN(n) ? "$" : "$" + getInputValue(inputElement).toLocaleString();
    }
    
    number.addEventListener('input', (e) => {
      formatInputValue(e.target);
      // Apply a formula
      let n = getInputValue(e.target);
    
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="currency-field" id="currency-field" class="number form-custom" placeholder="0,000,000">
<input id="face_value" name="face_value" class="number2 form-custom">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```js
$("#currency-field").keyup(function () {
    var value = $(this).val().replace(/[^0-9]+/g, "");
    $("#face_value").val(value);
});
```

Así solo tomará los números del primer input, no importando si insertas cualquier otro carácter.